# How to transfer a file between two AWS different servers using pem files, while on a local system

Tags: 16.04, transfer, copy-and-paste

**local to remote (upload)** *working*

```
scp -i remote.pem ~/Downloads/file.zip ubuntu@1.1.1.1:/var/www/html
```

**remote to local (download)** *working*

```
scp -i remote.pem ubuntu@1.1.1.1:/var/www/html/file.zip ~/Downloads
```

**remote1 to remote2 (transfer between 2 servers from local)** *NOT WORKING :(*

```
scp -i remote1.pem ubuntu@1.1.1.1:/var/www/html/file.zip remote2.pem ubuntu@1.1.1.1:/var/www/html
```

**Error is as following:**

```
 - Host key verification failed. 
 - lost connection 
 - ubuntu@1.1.1.1: Permission denied (publickey). 
 - lost connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create ssh key pair (private key `/home/ubuntu/id_rsa` and public key `/home/ubuntu/id_rsa.pub`) on remote1 server than append content of public key to /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys on remote2 server.

After that you can copy file without remote.pem file

```
ubuntu@server1:~$ scp /var/www/html/file.zip ubuntu@server2:/var/www/html
```

**Upd:**
From local system

```
ssh -i remote1.pem ubuntu@1.1.1.1 'scp /var/www/html/file.zip ubuntu@server2:/var/www/html'
```

Comment: Your solution worked, thanks. But do you know, like I asked, isn't there a way to use pem files for this task?

Comment: Hi @zarpio, sorry. I've updated the answer

Comment: The updated command from the local system not working gives me this error: cp: cannot stat 'ubuntu@1.1.1.1': No such file or directory

Comment: You are right. Fixed

Comment: Great now it is working. Can we still extend it further, what if we don't have authorized_key for server2, can we use pems for both servers?